# Resample Time Series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I have a data frame which contains multiple records in time—specifically every 4 minutes. I want to plot the time series to get daily multiple values of that temperature. Nevertheless, the data plots every value in a single manner and not daily, as I want.

```
df = pd.read_csv("my_file.csv")
print (df.head())
```

Output

```
                       Temperature
Date/Time
2015-07-01 00:00:47        25.21
2015-07-01 00:01:48        25.23
2015-07-01 00:02:48        25.33
2015-07-01 00:03:47        25.22
2015-07-01 00:04:48        25.32
```

When I plot with seaborn I get this:

```
df = df.reset_index()
sns.relplot(x= "Date/Time", y="Temperature", data=df, kind="line")
plt.show()
```

[image]

This is not what I want to plot; I want to something like this example:

[image]

I believe that I have to resample the data, but I get the average of that day. Therefore, one single value and not multiple values for a day.

```
df = df.resample("H").mean()
print (df.head())
```

Output:

```
                      Temperature
Date/Time
2015-07-01 00:00:00    25.264167
2015-07-01 01:00:00    25.267167
2015-07-01 02:00:00    25.272000
2015-07-01 03:00:00    25.290167
2015-07-01 04:00:00    25.307333
```

[image]
Not what I need. Can you help me?

Comment: you can find different time series frequencies string aliases here(https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases), you can also use `df.resample("2H").mean()` for resampling every two hours etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is not working. I even wrote an example of doing so. That method just resamples the data into a two hours average. To plot such a figure, you need to have multiple values in the same day. This means you do not have to average everything to a single value, in this case, a single value every 2 hours.

Comment: if you want to resample for a day , use `df.resample("D").mean()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is just exactly what I wrote in the post. Probably you are not understanding the problem. The idea is to gather all the information into a day with multiple values, not a single one. Therefore, the proposition is just what I did and is incorrect. It is more complex. I appreciate your intention for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a better way to bin the timestamps, but I'm drawing a blank right now.

Here is one way to do it: create a new column where you drop part of the date/time information so that all rows that fall in that timeframe share hte same value.

for ex, if you want to bin by hours:

`df['Binned time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00'))`

or by days:

`df['Binned time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'))`

then use lineplot:

`sns.lineplot(data=df, x='Binned time', y='data')`

[image]

Comment: I tried to drop the non-useful part and I could not. With your answer worked! Thank you very much for your time.